Deleting a header or footer
I have mistakenly created an unwanted message footer entry.  While I can easily disable this entry, there is no option for deleting it.  It has never been used in a mailing.  Can I simply delete the record from the civicrm_mailing_component table?

That seems fine. You could also delete it with api explorer (entity MailingComponent).

Thanks. I deleted it with phpMyAdmin with no consequence.
